# How to split a new window and run a command in this new window using tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have tried

```
tmux -c "shell command" split-window
```

but it does not seem to work.

Using `tmux split-window`, one can split a new window.

**UPDATE**:

Using `tmux split-window 'exec ping g.cn'` can run the ping command , but when stoped the new window will be closed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use:

```
tmux split-window "shell command"
```

The `split-window` command has the following syntax:

> ```
>  split-window [-dhvP] [-c start-directory] [-l size | -p percentage] [-t
>          target-pane] [shell-command] [-F format]
> ```

(from [`man tmux`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html), section "Windows and Panes"). Note that the order is important - the command has to come *after* any of those preceding options that appear, and it has to be a single argument, so you need to quote it if it has spaces.

---

For commands like `ping -c` that terminate quickly, you can set the `remain-on-exit` option first:

```
tmux set-option remain-on-exit on
tmux split-window 'ping -c 3 127.0.0.1'
```

The pane will remain open after `ping` finishes, but be marked "dead" until you close it manually.

If you don't want to change the overall options, there is another approach. The command is run with `sh -c`, and you can exploit that to make the window stay alive at the end:

```
tmux split-window 'ping -c 3 127.0.0.1 ; read'
```

Here you use the shell [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#read) command to wait for a user-input newline after the main command has finished. In this case, the command output will remain until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the pane, and then it will automatically close.

Comment: I like to use `; cat` instead, so I have to explicitly hit `<ctrl-c>` to kill the window. I often hit `<enter>` to break up output, so `read` isn't enough.

Answer (score 10):

**`bash --rcfile`**

This technique opens a new shell, runs commands, and leaves you there after the commands finish:

```
tmux-split-cmd() ( tmux split-window -dh -t $TMUX_PANE "bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc;$*')" )
tmux-split-cmd 'cd; pwd; ping google.com'
```

Or if the command has no special terminal characters like `;` just:

```
tmux-split-cmd ping google.com
```

This uses:

- `--rcfile`: [How to invoke bash, run commands inside the new shell, and then give control back to user? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-new-shell-then-give-control-back-to-user)
- `TMUX_PANE`: [How to split the window that ran the "tmux split-window" command instead of the current one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439031/how-to-split-the-window-that-ran-the-tmux-split-window-command-instead-of-the/439032#439032)

Another interesting variant is:

```
tmux-split-cmd-uniq() (
  if [ "$(tmux list-panes | wc -l | cut -d' ' -f1)" -ne 1 ]; then
    tmux kill-pane -t 1
  fi
  tms "$@"
)
```

which kills the previous split if it already exists, and helps to keep only one extra split at all times.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
tmux split-window
tmux send "ping -c 3 127.0.0.1" ENTER
```

The benefit is that the new pane will always be alive and never be closed, while  the previous answer `tmux split-window 'ping -c 3 127.0.0.1 ; read'` will close the session after the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.