# How to split the window that ran the "tmux split-window" command instead of the current one?

Tags: tmux

For example, if I run from window 0:

```
sleep 2;tmux split-window -h
```

and switch to another window 1 with `prefix-n` before the sleep is over, the window split happens on the new window 1.

How to make the split always happen on window 0 when the command is run from window 0, regardless of the current window?

I have found this possibility:

```
win="$(tmux display-message -p '#I')";sleep 2;tmux split-window -h -t "$win"
```

based on: https://superuser.com/questions/385472/get-current-window-number-for-bash-prompt but I don't like it forces me to run an extra command before `sleep 2` (which is a real useful command that takes a long time to finish in my use case), which is cumbersome.

Tested on tmux 2.5.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tmux-users/ZtEuCZQS_lI

Answer (score 2):

**`$TMUX_PANE`**

tmux automatically defines this variable for us, and it just works:

```
sleep 2;tmux split-window -h -t $TMUX_PANE
```

This gives focus to the split when it gets created, this can be prevented with `-d`:

```
sleep 2;tmux split-window -dh -t $TMUX_PANE
```