# How to generate new console in text mode linux

Tags: linux, gnome, console

In GNOME mode linux, we can use:

```
gnome-terminal
```

to generate a new console.

I am running linux in text/server mode ( No GNOME installed )

How can I generate a new console like gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are logged in directly to the console, you can switch between six built-in virtual consoles with `Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6]`.

If you would like to have a virtual console to which you can connect from any login (e.g. SSH), the most popular terminal multiplexers are [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) and [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). Tmux and screen allow you to open many windows, name windows and sessions, script keyboard shortcuts, and more. I personally use tmux and consider it one of my core tools.

If you want a graphical terminal emulator, you will need to install a desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, etc.)

Comment: How to do it from script to generate a tmux screen with some commands? ex: I want to generate a new screen(tmux session), and the new console should do 'ls' automatically when it starts.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432111/402314) looks like the best way to go about what you're asking.