# Use bash functions in tmux run-shell command

Tags: bash, tmux

I am trying to implement a feature of opening files in vim using ranger in separate tmux pane. It works if define commands directly in .tmux.conf. But having much code there doesn't look good, so I am trying to move it into functions and source them in .bashrc, but this yelds `'tmux__ranger_to_vim' returned 127`. Why tmux `run-shell` doesn't see functions defined in `.bashrc` and is it possible to make them available for it?

.bashrc

```bsh
    function tmux__current_pane_has_process {
      test -n "$1" || { echo "No process name" >&2; return 1; }
      pattern='^[^TXZ ]+ +'"${1}"'$'
      ps -o state= -o comm= | grep -iqE "$pattern"
    }
    
    function tmux__ranger_to_vim {
      tmux__current_pane_has_process 'ranger' || return 0
      tmux send-keys 'y'
      sleep .01
      tmux send-keys 'p'
      tmux select-pane -L
      tmux__current_pane_has_process 'n?vim' || return 0
      tmux send-keys ':tabe ' C-r * C-m
    }
```

.tmux.conf

```bsh
bind-key t run-shell "tmux__ranger_to_vim"
```

Answer (score 2):

`tmux run-shell` runs command as `sh -c` which doesn't source `.bashrc`. Also on some systems `sh` is not a bash at all but `dash`. So one have to explicitly source the file where required function defined before calling it:

```bsh
bind-key t run-shell 'bash -c "source ~/.tmux.bash ; tmux__ranger_to_vim"'
```

Comment: `--rcfile` is only used for interactive shell invocations. Running the `bash` command that you show would never use the `--rcfile` file since it's not starting an interactive shell.  On the other hand, if `BASH_ENV` was set to the pathname of a file, that file would be sourced for non-interactive shells.

Comment: @Kusalananda but for me it just worked. Bash man page says `rcfile` is used instead of standard `.bashrc` when shell is interactive but it doesn't say `rcfile` is not used when shell is non-interactive, unless invoked as `sh`. Also I saw usage of `rcfile` without `i` flag in this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432111/390120

Comment: Well, I can't get this to work on my system since `bash` does _not_ use `--rcfile` for non-interactive shells.